# Is it bad for performance to use ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString() in my Android project?

Tags: android, reflection, apache-commons-lang

I've read that reflection can cause performance issues on Android, so I'm wondering if using the ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString() method would be a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString()` uses reflection to do it's work, it is very likely to be slower then building the String representation of your class manually.

Whether it's a bad thing or not depends on your application. If `toString()` is called very often, the performance impact will be bigger, than it would be if it is only called a few times. If you want to be really sure you will have to measure the performance.